# 'cannot find symbol' compilation error when compiling a class of a package

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol, java-package

I created a directory named **mypack** and added a Java file inside that directory named as **A.java** .
The code for **A.java** is as follows:

```
package mypack;

public class A{
    public A(){
        System.out.println("Inside A");
    }
}
```

And I added another file in the same directory named **Demo.java** . The code for this file is as follows:

```
package mypack;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I compile the second file **Demo.java** I get error as such : **cannot find symbol A**

[image: Unknown symbol A]

the directory **mypack** looks like this :

[image: Directory structure]

I don't know why **Demo.java** the file of the same package (mypack) as that of A.java can't access class **A** even when I declared it as public in **A.java**.
Please somebody help!!

Comment: You should compile from your `Desktop` directory - the compiler will then look in a `mypack` directory for other classes in that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use

```
javac *.java
```

to complie two java source files at once.

Answer (score 0):

To compile the file, open your terminal and type

```
javac filename.java
```

To run the generated class file, use

```
java filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to compile the files that are needed, just as the case you have mentioned in your question:

```
javac Demo.java A.java
```

This compiles your class along with the dependency `A.java` in this case.

Or you could do something like this, to cover all the `.java` files that you have under your directory.

```
javac *.java
```

Please refer to [this](http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-the-javac-command/) for further reference!